# Minecraft rank system kotlin display rank befor username

Tags: java, kotlin, config, minecraft

I'm doing a rank system for Minecraft in kotlin. Now I would like to display the rank in front of the player name in the tabluator and in chat messages

Chat example:
[Owner] Fabboy: Hello world
[User] Player: Hey Fabboy

Does anyone know how I do it?
(The ranks are saved in the config, Minecraft 1.17.1, Java 16)

I am not a professional in programming with Kotlin so I would be very grateful for a detailed answer

The code:

```kotlin
package dev.fabboy.bork

import net.kyori.adventure.text.Component
import net.kyori.adventure.text.TextComponent
import org.bukkit.Bukkit
import org.bukkit.entity.Player
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler
import org.bukkit.event.Listener
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin
import org.bukkit.scoreboard.DisplaySlot

const val version = "0.1"

//
lateinit var INSTANCE: Bork

class Bork : JavaPlugin(), Listener {

    override fun onEnable() {
        INSTANCE = this
        println("----------\n[Bork] Plugin loaded \nVersion: $version\nVersion from: 2021-09-07\n${(System.currentTimeMillis())}\n----------")
        server.pluginManager.registerEvents(this, this)
        getCommand("broadcast")?.setExecutor(Broadcast())
        getCommand("setrank")?.setExecutor(setrank())
        getCommand("rank")?.setExecutor(rank())



    }

    override fun onDisable() {
        Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage("[Bork] Plugin Disabled")
    }

    @EventHandler
    fun onJoin(joinEvent: PlayerJoinEvent) {
        val player = joinEvent.player
        var j = this.config.get("Bork.${player.uniqueId}.joins", 0) as Int
        var r = this.config.get("Bork.${player.uniqueId}.rank", 1) as Int
        j += 1

        var ranker = ""
        if(r == 1){
            ranker = "§3User"
        }
        if(r == 2){
            ranker = "§dVIP"
        }
        if(r == 3){
            ranker = "§6Admin"
        }
        if(r == 4){
            ranker = "§cOwner"
        }

        player.sendMessage("§e-------------§r§lPrivate§r§e--------------§r\n§lWelcome§r\n${(player.displayName() as TextComponent).content()}\nThis is your: §e§l$j Join§r\nYour Rank: $ranker §r\n§e----------------------------------§r\nRanks:\n1. §3User§r\n2. §dVIP§r\n3. §6Admin§r\n4. §cOwner§r\n§e-------------§r§lPrivate§r§e--------------")

        this.config.set("Bork.${player.uniqueId}.joins", j)
        this.config.set("Bork.${player.uniqueId}.rank", r)
        this.saveConfig()

    }

}
```

Comment: What is your current code ? Like what did you already make ?

Comment: You can [edit] your question to include all details

Comment: i've added the code

Answer (score 0):

To change the chat message, you have to use the event `AsyncPlayerChatEvent`.

Java code:

```java
@EventHandler
public void onChat(AsyncPlayerChatEvent e) {
   Player p = (Player) e.getPlayer();
   e.setFormat(getRank(p) + " " + p.getDisplayName() + ": " e.getMessage()); // here you define the chat message
}
```

Kotlin code (something like that):

```kotlin
@EventHandler
fun onChat(e: AsyncPlayerChatEvent) {
   Player p = (Player) e.getPlayer();
   e.setFormat(getRank(p) + " " + p.getDisplayName() + ": " e.getMessage()); // here you define the chat message
}
```